# Managing listviews for large datas

Tags: android, listview

I am about to start a project with a lot of static data which will be entered into a list view. All these data will be divided into 3-4 different categories but there will be an `all-data` category that will incorporate all these categories. I wanted to know how is the most efficient way to implement this ?

I could always make separate classes for the 3-4 categories I have and finally for the all-data category populate them all. But what would be the most efficient way to do this ? Help please

Comment: What do the categories have to do with the list view?

Comment: @TedHopp suppose i have cat 1, cat 2 and cat 3; All these categories will have the same listView but different data. I am finally to combine all these categories into an all-data so what would be the most efficient way to implement this. do i fill out cat 1,2 and 3 separately and then call them onto all-data at last? or do i do the opposite ?

Comment: I meant, is the question about how to declare the static data or is it how to construct an adapter to display the data in the list view? Are all the data displayed in a single list view at the same time? Do the category names appear as labels in the list view?

Comment: @TedHopp they are to appear as category names in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to Android to handle this directly. The easiest thing might be to define each category as a separate list of items. Create a `ListAdapter` for each list, then append them all together using a [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) (a very nice third-party adapter that allows you to concatenate views and other adapters as if they were a single stream of data to be provided to a `ListView`. You can use explicit views for the category names that are to appear in the `ListView` or you can wrap each `ListAdapter` in a [`HeaderViewListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html).